# Building cob_people_perception with catkin_make

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi y'all,

I am trying to do face detection and position measurement with the Kinect for Windows v2 sensor. I have successfully calibrated the kinect camera and I need to port cob_people_perception over to my kinect v2 but while running catkin_make, I stumbled upon the following error:

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'cob_people_tracking_filter'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(cob_people_perception/cob_people_tracking_filter)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "cob_perception_msgs" with any of the following names:

    cob_perception_msgsConfig.cmake
    cob_perception_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "cob_perception_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "cob_perception_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "cob_perception_msgs" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cob_people_perception/cob_people_tracking_filter/CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package)
```

I'm wondering what I am missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211569/building-cob_people_perception-with-catkin_make/) by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2015-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Curiosa & curiosa.

I cloned
`cob_perception_common`
as in
`git clone https://github.com/ipa-rmb/cob_perception_common.git`,
cloned
`cob_common`,
`cd'ed` into the respective folders and did `catkin_ws$ rosdep install -r --from-paths .` for each folder cloned before doing `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"`and everything was honky-dory.

I wish there was a detailed README.md file that explicitly explained the installation process. Hope this helps someone someday.

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) with karma: 152 on 2015-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-06-18**:
Instead of duplicating these instruction in the README of every package the documentation is in the ROS wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Source

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-19**:
Also: @lakehanne: this really points to a missing dependency declaration in the `package.xml` of `cob_people_perception` or one of its dependencies. Have you reported the issue?

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2015-06-19**:
Yes, I have. Thank you!
Just a question I have. I am using the code with Kinect for Windows v2 sensor. I tried  `roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch` but I kept running into

> process[camera_base_link3-13]: started with pid [12958]
> [ INFO] [1434731961.261143212]: No matching device found.... wa

**Comment by [James7](https://answers.ros.org/users/29379/james7/) on 2017-02-16**:
Thanks, this made my day !!!!